# Linker error about -laudio

Tags: make, linker

I'm trying to `make` rcssmonitor and I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -laudio
```

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2. with gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: you need `libaudio`. How to get it depends on your distro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu/Mint. You should be able to get libaudio using:

```
apt-get install libaudio-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

This message tells you that the linker tries to find the file `libaudio.so`, either in the well known pathes ( might differ on distros )  `/lib, /lib64, /usr/lib, /usr/lib64`.
You also can tell the linker to search in other pathes with the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. 
And the library has to be installed somewhere.